# Upgrading to Rails 4.2 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to upgrade to Rails 4.2 from Rails 4.1.9 and when I attempt to run the console or the server i get the following error. Any thoughts? I thought the html-scanner gem was included with Action::View

```
gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_view/vendor/html-scanner (LoadError)
```

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0 and it has been bundled.

Comment: It looks like like it's an incompatibility with some of my gems. In this case prototype-rails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP's issue (and mine) was to do with an incompatibility in the prototype-rails gem. This can be fixed by using the "4.2" branch of prototype-rails directly from github. Modify your Gemfile entry as follows:

```
gem 'prototype-rails', github: 'rails/prototype-rails', branch: '4.2'
```

Note that the prototype-rails gem will not be supported from Rails 5 onwards, so now would be as good a time as any to remove this dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I believe they removed html-scanner from rails in 4.2 when they switched to [`rails-html-sanitizer`](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer) according to the [upgrade guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rails-html-sanitizer) but it seems you can use the [`rails-deprecated_sanitizer` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-deprecated_sanitizer) to your Gemfile to then re-include the html-scanner library

```
gem 'rails-deprecated_sanitizer'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried adding that gem at one point and it still didn't work. I'll try it again.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer per say but it's close if folks need to use the old sanitizer. The issue in particular was some outdated gems.

Comment: It worked for me, however, I had to install the gem manually using `gem install rails-deprecated_sanitizer`, it did not work when I added it to Gemfile and did `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this problem on a legacy project. It's a bundler 1.17.3 / ruby 2.4 / rails 4.2.11.3 and it was driving me up the wall.

The following nasty hack worked:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-deprecated_sanitizer'
gem 'prototype-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails.git', branch: '4.2'
```

but that wasn't enough. I then had to get rails-deprecated_sanitizer to appear where the gems wanted it.

So in my project, I created lib/action_view/vendor/html-scanner.rb:

```
require 'rails-deprecated_sanitizer'
require 'rails/deprecated_sanitizer/railtie'
require 'rails/deprecated_sanitizer/html-scanner'
```

(I doubt all three are needed, mind)

This depends on lib being in your load paths of course.

That fixed the problem, and I was finally able to reset the db and launch the server.